# Writing down the Oral Law

Tags: mitzvah, writing-printing, oral-torah

If the rabbis consider it Biblically forbidden to write down the Torah she'al peh, why is it not listed as one of the 613 mitzvot by Rambam and others

Comment: Seems like it is a detail of the mitzvah of writing a sefer torah.

Comment: @Yishai Interesting! Why not in the mitzva of Talmud Torah?

Comment: Where does it say it a biblical issur

Comment: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/7870/why-was-torah-shebal-peh-not-allowed-to-be-written?rq=1 and http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/7894/why-can-people-write-torah-shebal-peh-nowadays?rq=1

Answer (score 2):

There are different opinions regarding this ruling of דברים שבעל פה אי אתה רשאי לאומרן בכתב.

Rabbi Shlomo Zalman Ehrenreich suggested [that](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14547&st=&pgnum=105) the Rambam doesn't bring this ruling because in his opinion it's only Rabbinically forbidden.

Opinions that it's Biblical:
שו"ת חתם סופר או"ח סי' ר"ח. גם בס' חרדים (פ"ב מצות התלויות בעינים) עיי"ש, וכ"כ בשו"ת תשב"ץ ח"א סי' ב', וראה שד"ח פאת השדה מערכת ד' כלל ד', ישרש יעקב הובא בברכ"י דלקמן.

Opinions that it's Rabbinical:
בס' יראים השלם סי' רס"ח סב"ל דהוה איסור דרבנן, וכ"כ בתוס' ישנים יומא ע,א, ד"ה ובעשור שכתב וז"ל: ובעשור שבחומש הפקודים קורא על פה, אומר רבי שאע"פ שדרשו בגיטין (דף ס' ע"ב) שדברים שבכתב אי אתה רשאי לאומרם בעל פה אין זה אלא למצוה מן המובחר לקרות אותו שבכתב בכתב ושבעל פה בעל פה, וכאן משום כבוד ציבור לא הטריחו חכמים עכ"ל, וכ"כ בתוס' הרא"ש ותור"פ שם, וכן משמע מהריטב"א שם, ועי' גם בס' ברכי יוסף ומחזיק ברכה או"ח סי' מ"ט, ובס' יעיר אזן מערכת ד' אות ב', ובשו"ת מכתב לחזקיהו סי' ה', וראה שו"ת יחוה דעת ח"ג סי' ע"ד ועוד.

Comment: Here's the problem. If it's only Rabbinic, there would not be a need for a pasuk (albeit one from Psalms) to justify it. If it is Biblical, a verse from Psalms is not sufficient since prophets are not permitted to change Biblical law.

Comment: Rabbi Judah bar Nachmeini draws upon biblical sources in Gittin 60b. But a verse can be an [Asmachta](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asmachta_(Talmudical_hermeneutics)) and so be rabbinic.

Comment: @user5551 can you find me a biblical source for the biblical commandment, discussed in the Talmud in Taanit, of pouring water on Sukkot?