# Explanations for forbidding writing Oral Torah

Tags: history, oral-torah

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why was Torah sheBal Peh not allowed to be Written?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/7870/why-was-torah-shebal-peh-not-allowed-to-be-written)

The Wikipedia article for [Oral Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oral_Torah#Prohibition_to_write_the_Oral_Torah) mentions the possibility that it was forbidden to write and publish Oral Torah.

Has there been any explanation about why God has forbidden writing Oral Torah (at least initially)?